# Reactjs - Basic column splitting using flexbox

Tags: reactjs, flexbox

I'm currently trying to learn the basics of React so I thought I'd try to mock-up another website. Currently, I'm trying to build a header that looks like Airbnb's 
[image]

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out the aligning and how to get the logo to be all the way on the left side.

[image]

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
<Flexbox flexDirection="column">
            <Flexbox element="header" height="60px">
                <div style={{ flexGrow: 0}}>
                    <img src={Logo} />
                </div>
                <div style={{flexGrow: 8}}>
                    <SearchBar
                        onChange={() => console.log('onChange')}
                        onRequestSearch={() => console.log('onRequestSearch')}
                        style={{
                            margin: '0 auto',
                            maxWidth: 800
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Button>Become a host</Button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Button>Sign up</Button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Button>Log in</Button>
                </div>
            </Flexbox>
        </Flexbox>
```

Comment: Try adding a `marginRight: 'auto'` on your `img` wrapper `style` prop

Comment: thanks that did it for me! :-)